# Which is more efficient calling M,F,A or making a fun that aliases an existing static function?

Tags: erlang

For example for gen_tcp vs SSL. Some connections will use SSL and some Http. I can save this into my state as Module=gen_tcp OR I can save it as MyFun=fun gen_tcp:send/2, then I can do

```
Module:send(Socket,Data)
OR
MyFun(Sock,Data)
```

which of these methods is more efficient or recommended? I heard apply is slower than funs and doing MFA is just an apply. Are funs referencing static functions any faster than regular funs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in speed for an operation like this will never be measurable in a real-world program (particularly one dealing with I/O). You should think about what kind of API you want: passing a single callback module that exports send/2 and possibly other functions (maybe adding callback functions in future versions), or passing a specific functional value for each specific user-defined function to be called.

Comment: This tcp/ssl problem aways make me think parameterized modules must be part of the language. The proper implementation would make a module type appear which would be used even for non-parameterized modules. Plain atoms are referring too much in the system: modules, functions, registered processes, and real values.

Comment: Yes, passing around atoms was never a good solution to this sort of thing. But it's simple and tends to work...